# How to Set a Value Dynamically to the WPF datagrid Cells

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

I have created a WPF datagrid and the columns are static (costume columns). Data grid rows are binding as per the data from data table rows. I want to set values to the WPF `DataGrid` cells dynamically from another `ArrayList`.

I'm not finding the cell index of rows, like `dataGrid.Rows[i].Cells[j] = ArrayList[k]`.

Can anyone please help me? I'm new to WPF.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

if you have static ArrayList, your code can be like this:

```
<Grid Name="MyArray" Margin=”10”>
    <Grid.DataContext>
        <x:Array Type=”sys:String”>
        <sys:String>Red</sys:String>
        <sys:String>Yellow</sys:String>
        <sys:String>Lime</sys:String>
        <sys:String>Cyan</sys:String>
        <sys:String>Blue</sys:String>
        <sys:String>Magenta</sys:String>
        </x:Array>
    </Grid.DataContext>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width=”*”/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <!--here your dataGrid-->
    then you should write like this
    <Label Content="{Binding ElementName=MyArray, Path=DataContext[0]}" />
    and so on...
    </Grid>
```

correct me if I understand you wrong.

Comment: if your arraylist is dynamic, you can access `Grid.DataContext` property in code-behind, and write this: `Grid.DataContext = MyDynamicArrayList`, e.g. after `Initialize()`, and delete DataContext definition from xaml.

Comment: and `<Label Content="{DynamicResource ElementName=MyArray, Path=DataContext[0]}" />`

Comment: I have a Wpf dataGrid with 26 static columns(time bar).And My First 2 columns Are Binding Through A dataTable coming from database.and I collected The other data From Database and Stored in  an ArrayList.now i Want to Display Dyanamically That Arraylist data in Datagrid Cells as per specific condition [ if (stdtime == dataGrid.Columns[k].Header.ToString()) ],but i m unable to find how to set that values...[like windows form--->datagrid.Rows[].cells[]==some value].

Comment: I think that Items collection property of DataGrid is what you need. It's like the Row, but a bit smarter. try look around msdn, there are lot of examples.